# systemd and ExecStart with arguments with parsing errors

Tags: linux, shell, systemd

I have created a fluidsynth service with this ".service" file:

```
[Unit]
Description=fluidsynth-ng
After=xsynth-network.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/fluidsynth-ng.conf
ExecStart=/usr/bin/fluidsynth -a $AUDIO_DEVICE -c $AUDIO_BUFFERS -z $BUFFER_SIZE -r $SAMPLE_RATE -s -o shell.port=9988 -m $MIDI_DRIVER -i
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
PIDFile=/tmp/fluidsynth-ng.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem is I want to pass port parameter to ExecStart but it doesn't work:

```
[Unit]
Description=fluidsynth-ng
After=xsynth-network.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/fluidsynth-ng.conf
ExecStart=/usr/bin/fluidsynth -a $AUDIO_DEVICE -c $AUDIO_BUFFERS -z $BUFFER_SIZE -r $SAMPLE_RATE -s -o shell.port=$SERVER_PORT -m $MIDI_DRIVER -i
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
PIDFile=/tmp/fluidsynth-ng.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I think there's a problem with $SERVER_PORT parse, because I get this error: "fluidsynth: error: Failed to bind server socket"

EnvironmentFile looks correct:

```
AUDIO_DEVICE=jack
SERVER_PORT=9988
SAMPLE_RATE=48000
AUDIO_BUFFERS=2
BUFFER_SIZE=64
MIDI_DRIVER=alsa_seq
```

Any help?

Comment: There might be something else occupying that port. Check carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Launch either `ss -tulp` or `netstat -tulp` to check which ports are open and which process is listening on your port 9988, and you will probably see some other instance of your process already listening, so you can't assign the port to a different process.

Comment: No, it's not a port problem. The problem is with -o shell.port=$SERVER_PORT. It doesn't translate $SERVER_PORT to 9988. I think it's because "=$" combination